# Не удается активировать виртуальную среду

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Для проекта Django я создал виртуальную среду внутри проекта. Но при запуске команды
**PS C:\Users\joray\Documents\invoice_export-master> cd .\env\Scripts\activate** в терминале VS code я получаю следующую ошибку:

```
cd : Не удается найти путь ".\env\Scripts\activate", так как он не существует.
строка:1 знак:1
+ cd .\env\Scripts\activate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\env\Scripts\activate:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

При запуске виртуальной среды с той же командой в терминале Windows 10 никаких проблем не возникает. В чем мой косяк?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cd - это команда для перехода в другую директорию.
А вам надо просто запустить activate
`.\env\Scripts\activate`